# appBar iconStyleRight syntax error

Tags: material-ui

I have

```
render() {
    return <AppBar style={{ position: "fixed" }} title={<span>my Title</span>}

        iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationMenu /></IconButton>}
        iconStyleRight={{color:"red"}}
        iconElementRight={<IconButton><span className = "material-icons">account_circle</span></IconButton>}
        />
}
```

but iconStyleRight is giving me the error

```
Type '{ [x: number]: undefined; color: any; }' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

No idea why. I've tried many combinations, including adding a `style` to the `<span>` element, which is ignored.

Would appreciate correct syntax for making this right icon appear in red, so that I can understand how to apply styles to my icons.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the solution is to set the iconStyle attribute of the IconButton component.

Also in my current environment in material-ui.d.ts the typedef of iconStyleRight attribute was erroneously set to 'string', but should have been object, compounding the problem.

All good now.